# What code highlighting libs are there for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax-highlighting, ramaze, codehighlighter

What'd also interest me is which have more or less dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See also the [Ultraviolet](http://ultraviolet.rubyforge.org/) library.

> Ultraviolet is a syntax highlighting engine based on Textpow. Since it uses Textmate syntax files, it offers out of the box syntax highlighting for more than 50 languages and 20 themes.
>
> Ultraviolet is at the same time a stand-alone command line utility and a Ruby library.

Comment: Ultraviolet is a great library. It has lots of dependencies though (through Textpow and Onigurama, which isn't very easy to install on all old systems)

Comment: This is true, but I just wanted to throw it out there to ensure many options are covered.  :)

Answer (score 7):

I'm using [Coderay](http://coderay.rubychan.de/) ([see it in action at the bottom of this article](http://blog.logeek.fr/2008/3/31/data-visualization-with-ruby-and-rmagick-where-are-those-bikes))

Not sure how many (if any) dependencies it has.

Comment: It is much better than ultraviolet

Answer (score -5):

[Google is our friend](http://www.google.hu/search?q=ruby+syntax+highlighting+library&btnG=Keres%C3%A9s&hl=hu&sa=2)...

First hit: http://syntax.rubyforge.org/chapter-1.html#s1